# passport login with JWT

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm trying to implement login endpoint with passport.js. My user schema contains nickname and password. So far in app.js I have:

```
require('./config/passport');
app.use('/user',  passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), require('./routes/user/login.js'));
```

I require my file passport.js which have passport strategy configuration:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'nickname' }, (nickname, password, done) => {
        User.findOne({ nickname: nickname })
            .then(user => {
                if(!user) {
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Email and/or password is not valid' });
                }
                bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    if(isMatch) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(null, false, { message: 'Email and/or password is not valid' });
                    }
                });
            });
    })
);

passport.use(new JWTStrategy({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: keys.secretJWT
    },
    function (jwtPayload, cb) {
        return User.findOneById(jwtPayload.id)
            .then(user => {
                return cb(null, user);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                return cb(err);
            });
    })
);
```

and in app.js (first snippet) on `/user` I'm requirung actual endpoint which is:

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {

        console.log(info);

        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Email and/or password is not valid',
                user: user
            });
        }
        req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
            if (err) next(err);
            //generate a signed JWT with the contents of user object and return it in the response
            const token = jwt.sign(user, keys.secretJWT);
            return res.json({user, token});
        });
    })(req, res);
});
```

so in the end it is invoked when calling `/user/login`. Weird to me is that `console.log(info);` never actually consoles, I can't see it in terminal in which my node app is running.

I'm passing valid nickname and password but I always get 401 Unauthorized:

[image]

What am I missing? Maybe it's because I'm not passing token? But on login I don't know the token. It should be in response of login. And then I will authenticate with token on further requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing your strategy alias in passport.use() function. You use a alias `jwt` in your router:
    `passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false})`

So your passport.use() function should look like this:

```
passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy(...), function(payload, cb){...})
passport.use('jwt', new JWTStrategy(...), function(payload, cb){...})
```

Otherwise you cant match a proper strategy with an alias. Also in a login controller you have to call passport with a 'local' alias in this case.